# How can I use in inheritance in Yii framework controller

Tags: php, inheritance, yii

In below code I wrote some functions twice in Index() function and in   teamSetgoalstatus() also. How can I avoid to write it twice.

```
class User_dashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {

        $set_dates=new SettingsForm;

        $set_dates=$set_dates->get_all_data();

        $setting_date=new SettingsForm;
        $where = 'where setting_content = :setting_content and year = :year';
        $list = array('setting_content','year');
        $data = array('PMS_display_format',date('Y'));             
        $settings_data = $setting_date->get_setting_data($where,$data,$list);          
        //print_r($settings_data);die();
        $curr_year=date("Y");
        $team_kra_appr=array();
        $Employee_id = Yii::app()->user->getState("Employee_id");
        $kra_info=new KpiAutoSaveForm;
        $emp_data = new EmployeeForm;
        $cluster = new ClusterForm;


        $Employee_id = Yii::app()->user->getState("Employee_id");
        $where = 'where Employee_id = :Employee_id';
        $list = array('Employee_id');
        $data = array($Employee_id);
        $emp_data_desc =$emp_data->get_employee_data($where,$data,$list);



        $Reporting_officer1_id=$emp_data_desc['0']['Email_id'];
        $where= 'where Reporting_officer1_id=:Reporting_officer1_id';
        $list= array('Reporting_officer1_id');
        $data= array($Reporting_officer1_id);
        $team_members=$emp_data->get_employee_data($where,$data,$list);
        $team=$emp_data->get_employee_data($where,$data,$list);

        $team_members= implode(', ', array_column($team_members, 'Employee_id'));

        $data=$team_members;
        $array = $team_members;
        $array = explode( ',', $array );
        foreach ($array as &$value){
            $value = "'" . trim($value)."'";
        }
        $array = implode(', ', $array);
        $year1=$settings_data['0']['setting_type'];
        $set_goal_sub=$kra_info->get_team_members_kra_sub($array,$year1);

        $employee_data =new EmployeeForm;

        $team_pend_appr=array();
        $kra_team_pend=$kra_info->get_pending_goal_team($array,$year1);
                for ($i=0; $i < count($kra_team_pend); $i++) { 
                $Employee_id=$kra_team_pend[$i]['Employee_id'];

                $employee_data =new EmployeeForm;
                $where = 'where Employee_id = :Employee_id';
                $list = array('Employee_id');
                $data = array($kra_team_pend[$i]['Employee_id']);
                $team_pend_appr = $employee_data->get_employee_data($where,$data,$list);

            }
        if (isset($emp_data_desc) && count($emp_data_desc)>0) {
            $where = 'where Email_id = :Email_id';
            $list = array('Email_id');
            $data = array($emp_data_desc['0']['cluster_appraiser']);
            $cluster_head =$emp_data->get_employee_data($where,$data,$list);
        }
        //print_r($cluster_head);die();
        $Employee_id = Yii::app()->user->getState("Employee_id");
        if (isset($emp_data_desc) && count($emp_data_desc)>0) {
            $where = 'where cluster_name = :cluster_name';
            $list = array('cluster_name');
            $data = array($emp_data_desc['0']['cluster_name']);
            $emp_data_desc =$cluster->get_cluster_data($where,$data,$list,'department');
        }

        // echo "<pre>";print_r($data);echo "</pre>";
        // echo count($kra_mid_appr);die();


        $team_set=array();
        $set_goal_sub=$kra_info->get_team_members_kra_sub($array,$year1);
        for($i=0;$i<count($set_goal_sub);$i++){
                $Employee_id=$set_goal_sub[$i]['Employee_id'] ;
                $where = 'where Employee_id = :Employee_id';
                $list = array('Employee_id');
                $data = array($set_goal_sub[$i]['Employee_id']);
                $team_set = $emp_data->get_employee_data($where,$data,$list);

            }

        $kpi_appr=$kra_info->get_disinct_kra_appr_team($array,$year1);
                for($i=0;$i<count($kpi_appr);$i++){
                $Employee_id=$kpi_appr[$i]['Employee_id'];



                $employee_data1=new EmployeeForm;
                $where = 'where Employee_id = :Employee_id';
                $list = array('Employee_id');
                $data = array($kpi_appr[$i]['Employee_id']);
                $team_kra_appr[$i] = $employee_data1->get_employee_data($where,$data,$list);

            }

        $my_activity=new NotificationsForm;
        $where ='where Employee_id = :Employee_id order by id desc';
        $list=array('Employee_id');
        $data=array($Employee_id);
        $my_recent_act=$my_activity->get_notifications($where,$data,$list);
        // echo "<pre>";
        // print_r($my_recent_act);die();
        // echo "</pre>";

        $this->render('//site/script_file');    
        $this->render('//site/header_view_layout');
        $this->render('//site/user_dashboard',
        array(
            'team'=>$team,
            'team_set'=>$team_set,
            'team_pend_appr'=>$team_pend_appr,
            'team_kra_appr'=>$team_kra_appr,


            ));
        $this->render('//site/footer_view_layout'); 
    }


    function actionteamSetgoalstatus()
    {

        $status = $_POST['status'];
        $value = explode('_',$status);
        $Employee_id = Yii::app()->user->getState("Employee_id");
        $kra_info=new KpiAutoSaveForm;
        $emp_data=new EmployeeForm;
        $employee_data=new EmployeeForm;
        $curr_year=date("Y");
        $kra_all_data=$kra_info->getdata();

        $setting_date=new SettingsForm;
        $where = 'where setting_content = :setting_content and year = :year';
        $list = array('setting_content','year');
        $data = array('PMS_display_format',date('Y'));             
        $settings_data = $setting_date->get_setting_data($where,$data,$list);

        $where = 'where Employee_id = :Employee_id';
        $list = array('Employee_id');
        $data = array($Employee_id);
        $emp_data_desc =$emp_data->get_employee_data($where,$data,$list);

        $Reporting_officer1_id=$emp_data_desc['0']['Email_id'];
        $where= 'where Reporting_officer1_id=:Reporting_officer1_id';
        $list= array('Reporting_officer1_id');
        $data= array($Reporting_officer1_id);
        $team_members=$emp_data->get_employee_data($where,$data,$list);
        $team_members= implode(', ', array_column($team_members, 'Employee_id'));
        $data=$team_members;
        $array = $team_members;
        $array = explode( ',', $array );
        foreach ($array as &$value1){
            $value1= "'" . trim($value1)."'";
        }
        $array = implode(', ', $array);
        $year1=$settings_data['0']['setting_type'];
        $set_goal_sub=$kra_info->get_team_members_kra_sub($array,$year1);

        if ($value[1] =='Submitted') {  
        for($i=0;$i<count($set_goal_sub);$i++){
                $Employee_id=$set_goal_sub[$i]['Employee_id'] ;
                $where = 'where Employee_id = :Employee_id';
                $list = array('Employee_id');
                $data = array($set_goal_sub[$i]['Employee_id']);
                $kra_data[$i] = $emp_data->get_employee_data($where,$data,$list);

            }
        }
        else if($value[1] == 'Pending')
        {
                $kra_team_pend=$kra_info->get_pending_goal_team($array,$year1);
                for ($i=0; $i < count($kra_team_pend); $i++) { 
                $Employee_id=$kra_team_pend[$i]['Employee_id'];
                $employee_data =new EmployeeForm;
                $where = 'where Employee_id = :Employee_id';
                $list = array('Employee_id');
                $data = array($kra_team_pend[$i]['Employee_id']);
                $kra_data[$i] = $employee_data->get_employee_data($where,$data,$list);

            }

        }
        else if($value[1] == 'Approved')
        {
                $kpi_appr=$kra_info->get_disinct_kra_appr_team($array,$year1);
                for($i=0;$i<count($kpi_appr);$i++){
                $Employee_id=$kpi_appr[$i]['Employee_id'];
                $where = 'where Employee_id = :Employee_id';
                $list = array('Employee_id');
                $data = array($kpi_appr[$i]['Employee_id']);
                $kra_data[$i] = $employee_data->get_employee_data($where,$data,$list);

            }
        }

        $content = '';
            if (isset($kra_data) && count($kra_data)>0) {

                for ($i=0; $i < count($kra_data); $i++) { 

                        if($value[1]=="Submitted")
                        {
                        if($content == '')
                        {   
                            $content = '<tr>'.'<td>'.$kra_data[$i]['0']['Employee_id'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$kra_data[$i]['0']['Emp_fname']."  ".$kra_data[$i]['0']['Emp_lname'].'</td>'.'<td>'."Submitted".'</td>'.'</tr>';
                        }
                        else
                        {   
                            $content = $content.'<tr>'.'<td>'.$kra_data[$i]['0']['Employee_id'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$kra_data[$i]['0']['Emp_fname']."  ".$kra_data[$i]['0']['Emp_lname'].'</td>'.'<td>'."Submitted".'</td>'.'</tr>';
                        }


                    }
                    else if($value[1]=="Pending")
                        {

                        if($content == '')
                        {   

                            $content = '<tr>'.'<td>'.$kra_data[$i]['0']['Employee_id'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$kra_data[$i]['0']['Emp_fname']."  ".$kra_data[$i]['0']['Emp_lname'].'</td>'.'<td>'."Pending".'</td>'.'</tr>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $content = $content.'<tr>'.'<td>'.$kra_data[$i]['0']['Employee_id'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$kra_data[$i]['0']['Emp_fname']."  ".$kra_data[$i]['0']['Emp_lname'].'</td>'.'<td>'."Pending".'</td>'.'</tr>';
                        }


                    }
                    else if($value[1]=="Approved")
                        {

                        if($content == '')
                        {   

                            $content = '<tr>'.'<td>'.$kra_data[$i]['0']['Employee_id'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$kra_data[$i]['0']['Emp_fname']."  ".$kra_data[$i]['0']['Emp_lname'].'</td>'.'<td>'."Approved".'</td>'.'</tr>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $content = $content.'<tr>'.'<td>'.$kra_data[$i]['0']['Employee_id'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$kra_data[$i]['0']['Emp_fname']."  ".$kra_data[$i]['0']['Emp_lname'].'</td>'.'<td>'."Approved".'</td>'.'</tr>';
                        }


                    }
                    }


            }
            else
            {
                $content = "No Record Found";
            }

            print_r($content);die();

        }

}
```

Comment: If it does exacly the same make a method in your model for example and call this method

Comment: can u tell me name of the functions, which u have written twice

Answer (score 0):

Better way to create one commonHelper file and write ur all utility function in this class, wherever you need just use it like this:

```
namespace app\common; 

class commonHelper {

public function nameOfTheFunction1(arg.....) {

    //code......
}

public function nameOfTheFunction2(arg.....) {

    //code......
}

public function nameOfTheFunction3(arg.....) {

    //code......
}
}

/*
   in ur controller, models, ect... use like this
*/

use app\common\commonHelper; //use ur commonHelper in this file

$common_helper = new commonHelper(); //make the object of commonHelper;

$result = $common_heper->nameOfTheFunction1(parmas); //now call the function
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller is a normal class as in plain PHP. Just extract that part of the code you want and create a new function that is either public, private or protected (I think in this case you won't need it anywhere else so it can be private). And call it as you would do it in a normal class with `$this->yourFunction($params...)`.

Yii's controllers are normal classes that get instantiated by Yii at runtime.